# Tensor and \Bigg \rangle

Tags: equations, tensor

consider the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
$$
\Bigg|0\Bigg\rangle_{\!\!\!\!\mathrm{g}}
$$
$$
 \tensor[_{\!\!\!\!\mathrm{g}}]{\Bigg\langle}{}0\Bigg|
$$
\end{document}
```

In the first equation I inserted `\!\!\!\!` since I want the `\mathrm{g}` very near the `\rangle`, and this works well. I would like also to have in the second equation but, this time neither `\!\!\!\!` nor `\qquad`, nor `\hspace*{2mm}` has effect. I can I get the `\mathrm{g}` come closer to the `\langle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the left hand version, place the `\mathrm{g}` and *afterwards* employ the negative kern (taken here as `-11mu` rather than `\!\!\!\!` = `-12mu`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
\[
\Biggl|0\Biggr\rangle_{\mkern-11mu\mathrm{g}}
\]
\[
 \tensor[_{\mathrm{g}\mkern-11mu}]{\Biggl\langle}{}0\Biggr|
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Thanks.  Done, with `-11mu`, which looks nicer.